# Function which take as input variable result from other function

Tags: python, function

As I'm new in python coding, I stuck on defining a function which take as input variable from other function. Generally my code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import configparser
import re

var="abc"
class Config:
    def getSources(var):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read("C\\configFile.ini")
        connection=config.get(connectinfo,'connectStr')

        if source in connection_source:
            print (connection_connectstr) 

        else: 
            print ('Something wrong') 
    return connection       

try:   
    emp1 = Config.getSources(var)
except configparser.NoSectionError:
        print ("Senction is not correct")

     def getTables(connection)
```

In few words, I get data from Config.ini file, then do some process. Next I want to create next function getTables which as input take result from first function. By the way in getSources I would like to make it as return statement, unfornatelly return is returning null... Print works fine.

Comment: Totally unclear... do you just want to add `return connection_connectstr` in your `getSources` function?

Comment: What do you want getSources to return? There is no return statement in that function so you should add one, e.g. `return connection`. For getTables to use that result, write `connection = getSources(var)`, `getTables(connection)`. By the way, `connection_connectstr` is undefined in getSources.

Comment: what exactly is unclear ? Take a look at connection variable inside getSource function. Then I'm trying to use that in getTables function.

Comment: so maybe `return connection` at some point in `getSource` (at the end if possible)  `connection`'s scope is local, conenxion doesn't exist outside of `getSource`

Comment: Hi all, I added return connection. But the thing is that it returning NULL value...

Comment: Please clean up your question. I don't understand your problem

Comment: could you try : `if config.has_option(connectinfo,'connectStr'):
   print config.get(connectinfo,'connectStr')` (also you have indentation problem for the `return`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value or raise an exception:

```
    
    if source in connection_source:
        return (connection_connectstr) 
    else: 
        raise configparser.NoSectionError('Something wrong')
```